# jface comboviewer autocomplete field mouse listener

Tags: java, combobox, autocomplete, swt, mouselistener

I have the following code

```
Composite composite = new Composite(parent, SWT.Border);
ComboViewer viewer = new ComboViewer(composite, SWT.DROP_DOWN);
viewer.add(new Object[]{aitem,bitem,citem,aitem2,etc});
Combo combo = viewer.getCombo();
new AutoCompleteField(combo, new ComboContentAdapter(), combo.getItems();
```

The code works fine and and as you expect, when you type in the combo box, the field autocompletes and there is a drop down with options to select. you can use arrow keys and enter to select an option, but if you try to click on an item in the autocomplete dropdown, you do not select it. How do I make it so when i start typing, i am able to click and select the item.

Comment: Does double click work?

Comment: doubleclick but doesnt actually select it, i would like it to select it with one left click. and  a selected item is stored